# What is Automatic Reference Counting's impact on an arrow -> dereference?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, ivar

If I say `self->ivar = [[Foo alloc] init];`, does ARC actually retain the new object? Or is this type of assignment used typically to prevent a retain?

Comment: What "new object", in relation to "->"? The RHS of the assignment is not related the question; consider if the LHS was not a "de-reference".

Answer (score 1):

> does ARC actually retain the new object?

That depends on the attributes of `ivar`. If `ivar` has strong ownership qualification (the default for most variables) then the object will be retained.

It doesn't matter how the variable is found; whether it is a local, global, implicit instance (just the variable name), explicit instance (e.g. `->` as in your sample), etc.; it only matters what the ownership qualifier on the variable is - ARC will do the right thing as indicated by the ownership qualifier.

HTH